# How to run sniffing demonstration using virtualbox and wireshark

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, wireshark

I am going to have a demonstration of packet sniffing using wireshark.

Therefore, I decided to create two vitual machines in virtualbox (with "host-only adapter" network config) and monitor the traffic between them using the wireshark installed on the host machine. This is fine, but I need root permission on the host machine, which I don't have.

1- One solution is finding a way to sniff without sudo access. This is risky and dangerous and it may not be possible.

2- The other solution is to create a third virtual machine that the traffic between the first two machines go through the third one and I can sniff using that machine (I definitely have the sudo access on my virtual machine).

I prefer the solution 2, but I don't know how to do it. Is there any way to do 2?

Answer (score 0):

Setup Squid Proxy Server on the third VM. Set all adapters to bridged. Proxy the traffic from the two test machines through Squid. Install wireshark on the proxy and monitor eth0. Have fun.

This guy probably has as good an answer for you as any. https://serverfault.com/questions/306024/how-to-route-network-traffic-of-a-host-via-another-host

Comment: Is this only web traffic?

Answer (score 0):

If your third virtual machine is on the same virtual network and you have root access on it, you can start sniffing in promiscuous mode - this will make all packets (even ones going to/coming from first and second virtual machine) land on the interface of the third virtual machine.

Keep in mind that the virtual network itself (and all 3 virtual machines) must be set up in a way, which allows packet capture (there is some hypervisors with such options).